# How to show housing numbers on MapBox?

Tags: android, mapbox

I use the MapBox in my android project. I need to show house numbers, but I do not find such an opportunity in the documentation.
I can get the house num label and I set color as Black but its invisible. 
I know that maps have such information and it is displayed in the Java engine. Any ideas?

Comment: Not all houses have numbers in the OpenStreetMap data that MapBox uses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some styles, there is simply no map of house numbers. But for those styles in which house numbers there are them you can display this:
Kotlin:

```
    map?.getLayer("housenum-label")?.setProperties(
            PropertyFactory.textColor(Color.DKGRAY),
            PropertyFactory.visibility(Property.VISIBLE)
    )
```

Comment: As always with Mapbox, this is outdated and it doesn't show anywhere what to use instead. They really had awesome docs when they started, now you have got to figure out everything by yourself. All I want is to show house numbers and road names and toggle it on and off. Should be easy enough, but of course, it's not, because why update docs?